# Who knows what the name of this put option is? It's like a conditional Asian option, but with an upper boundary

Tags: options, asian-option

Let $a < K < b$, then this option formula is:

$$\left(K - \frac{1}{\int_0^T\mathbb{1}_{\{a<S_t<b\}}dt}\int_0^TS_t\mathbb{1}_{\{a<S_t<b\}}dt\right)^{\large+}$$

Comment: This exotic option seems too special and less common to have a name.

Comment: Agree with @NN2, but i think you could sensibly call it something like a corridor asian call.